# Tkinter Button Will Not Get Focus on Click

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget, focus

I have this simple GUI app:

```
from tkinter import *

def Key(event):
    print(event.char)

root = Tk()

btn1 = Button(root, text='Button1')
btn1.pack(side=LEFT)
btn1.bind('<Key>', Key)

btn2 = Button(root, text='Button2')
btn2.pack(side=LEFT)
btn2.bind('<Key>', Key)

root.mainloop()
```

I would expect buttons to receive focus and start accepting `KeyPress` events when I click on them, as well as they should display a dotted line box indicating being in focus, but that does not happen. I have to use `Tab` to move focus.

Is this the expected behavior and why?

I know I can put focus on a widget programmatically. My question is only about why clicking on a button will not put focus on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the expected behavior. Personally I think it's the right behavior. Imagine using a text editor, and every time you click on the toolbar the main area loses focus. I think that would be infuriating.

That being said, I think the default for ttk buttons is to steal focus on a click.